# Jetpack Compose rememberSystemUiController setStatusBarColor flicker

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have two pages A and B with white and black background colors.

I need to change the status bar color when switching between two pages.

I use `rememberSystemUiController` to change the status bar color, but there is flickering, jerky, and the transition is not smooth.

[Blink effect YouTube](https://youtu.be/pD2LiJ0Y5wc)

```kotlin
@Composable
fun APager() {
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val background = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background

    SideEffect {
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(background)
    }

    // ...
}

@Composable
fun BPager() {
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val black = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.black

    SideEffect {
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(black)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Replace your SideEffect with `LaunchedEffect(Unit)` because you only want to set the statusbar color once, not on every single frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SideEffect launches with every recomposition and your composable is probably recomposing multiple times. Use LauncedEffect instead with a key whose value is set to the currently selected page of the pager. This will prevent launching the effect multiple times. Example:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyPager() {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

    LaunchedEffect(pagerState.currentPage) {
        val color = when (pagerState.currentPage) {
            0 -> Color.Blue
            1 -> Color.Green
            2 -> Color.Red
            else -> Color.Black
        }

        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color)
    }

    HorizontalPager(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        count = 10,
        state = pagerState,
    ) { page ->
        Text(
            text = "Page: $page",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you give the answer in code?

Comment: I added some sample code to my response.

Answer (score 0):

Flicker due to multiple recombination,Replace SideEffect with LaunchedEffect

```
val black = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.black
LaunchedEffect(black){
    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(black)
}
```

but, You can also add a lock

```
var isChange by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}
val black = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.black
SideEffect {
    if(isChange){
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(black).apply {
            isChange = false
        }
    }
}
```

I think the second method is better, and there is no problem switching pages quickly